Compile-time generated switch-case with no performance hit
I'm trying to refactor a lot of code in the project I'm working on, where my coworkers are copy-paste fans. Scattered across many classes, you can find dispatching functions like this:
void dispatch(const Buffer& buffer)
{
    switch (buffer.getId())
    {
    case Id::Type1:
    {
        Type1 obj;
        obj.deserialize(Buffer);
        // ... other code to print and process the buffer
    }
    break;
    case Id::Type2:
    {
        Type2 obj;
        obj.deserialize(Buffer);
        // ... same code to print and process the buffer as above
    }
    break;
    // ... and again, and again... for 10 to 30 types, depending on context
}

A few constraints for this problem:

we have no control over Type1, Type2... so we can't play with their hierarchy or interfaces. In some context, those types do inherit from a (too generic to be useful) common base class, but you can consider them effectively as unrelated types for the scope of this problem.
the code executed under each case is effectively the same if you see all types-related stuff as data that you can access through Id.
all types and id are and will be fully known at compile time. It seems obvious, but I prefer to spell it out.

This to me means that the switch-case is conceptually the correct solution, though extremely verbose and error-prone. My goal is then to refactor those functions so that I need only to code the case logic once and I can then focus on listing the id-type association somewhere else. All of this should be obtainable without any performance hit, which means the fully optimized code should use a jump table.
Now let's suppose I have some templated obj_type_t<Id> that "returns" the type corresponding to the Id (how to construct this will be the topic of another question) and let's focus on the switch-case.
My solution(s)
My simple approach was to use template recursion to automatically generate the switch-case:
// Base case
template <typename T, typename Predicate, DefaultPredicate>
void generateSwitch(T i, std::integer_sequence<T>, Predicate&& predicate, DefaultPredicate&& defaultPredicate)
{
    defaultPredicate();
}

// Recursive step
template <typename T, T First, T... Is, typename Predicate, DefaultPredicate>
void generateSwitch(T i, std::integer_sequence<T>, Predicate&& predicate, DefaultPredicate&& defaultPredicate)
{
    if (i == First)
    {
        predicate(First);
    }
    else
    {
        generateSwitch(i, std::integer_sequence<T, Is...>{}, predicate, defaultPredicate);
    }
}

So that I can use it as follows:
void dispatch(const Buffer& buffer)
{
    auto processBuffer = [buffer](auto Id) // this auto is actually an integral_constant, so it's ok to use it as a template parameter
    {
        obj_type_t<Id> obj;
        obj.deserialize(buffer);
        // other code to print and process the buffer
    };
    
    auto invalidId = [](){ std::cout << "Invalid Id"; }
    
    generateSwitch(buffer.getId(), std::integer_sequence<Id, Id::Type1, Id::Type2 /*, other types... */>{}, processBuffer, invalidId);
}

I later found out in this answer a neat trick to avoid template recursion, using a discardable std::initializer_list, like such:
template <typename T, T... Is, typename Predicate, DefaultPredicate>
void generateSwitch(T i, std::integer_sequence<T, Is...>, Predicate&& predicate, DefaultPredicate&& defaultPredicate)
{
    bool matched{false};
    std::initializer_list<int>({(i == Is ? predicate(std::integral_constant<T, Is>{}), matched = true, 0 : 0)...});
    if (!matched)
    {
        defaultPredicate();
    }
}

All good till this point. I finally put some code in compiler explorer and tried to confirm the two solutions were equivalent and optimizable to a jump table (ie, equivalent to a switch-case). Clang happily complied, but gcc, the compiler I'm working with, is unable to. It generates a sequence of jump-equal statement that even to an untrained human eye are easily translatable into a jump table. See this.
Is it possible to get my code or a different solution to compile down to a jump table?

I dont really have any experience with jump tables (First time hearing about it). But from what I reading about it my first tought was also to make a recursion. Ill see if I can find anything to help but this is way more advance then what Ive done untill now.

gcc sometimes doesn't generate a jump table even when compiling a literal switch statement. Try -fjump-tables --param case-values-threshold=2 (or whatever your usual number of cases is). Note, a jump table may or may not be more efficient than a (short) chain of compare-and-jump instructions.

How do you put a debugger breakpoint on the generateSwitch code? (e.g.) I want to breakpoint on type 5 in the "switch". Although clever, your approach may be "too clever". You could generate the [real] switch/case using a perl/python [metaprogramming] script during build into (e.g.) dynamic_switch.cpp which you then compile. Then, you have a simple switch/case [that everyone will understand] and more control than what you're proposing.

If Id are consecutive (or small range), you might create the table yourself (mostly replacing initializer_list by array of function).

You can always create your own jump table.  Use a table of <key, function pointer>.  When you find the key, dereference the associated function pointer.

Search the internet for "C++ subscriber pattern".

If the cure is worse than the disease, then don't "fix" it. That being said, generally you'd optimize it as: store all id data in a table, ideally sorted but not a must. Search through the table in search of an index matching the id, then call the corresponding function pointer. Probably(?) less branching, less code repetition, but potentially also function call overhead since compilers struggle to inline functions called through function pointers.

@CraigEstey I'm sorry but your way of thinking is really wrong IMO. I don't really like code-generation tools as a general rule as you should be able to solve all problems in c++. The objection about being unable to use a debugger could be applied to any templated code (and yes, I agree that it would be cool if debuggers would allow you to specify types and see the generated code), but we don't write a new container class for each type for that reason.

@Jarod42 this is kind of a simpler version of the function pointers table solution, is it not?

@Lundin yes, my understanding is that the function pointers table solution is way less optimizable. I'm going to try compiler-exploring it just for fun, but I'm 99% sure it'll be worse performace-wise

@ThomasMatthews already answered to the function pointers table solution in previous comment. As for subscriber pattern, what do you mean exactly? Are talking about an observer and the way they dispatch function calls to subscribed objects? Those implementations do indeed use some form of function tables, but I don't see how they relate to my situation (everything there is dynamic, I have all the information needed at compile time)

@AndreaBocco Function pointer tables usually mean more function call overhead but less branching. Depending on target, that may or may not be a good trade off. For high-end CPUs like x86 it might be efficient despite the call overhead since you get rid of branches. Also, function pointer tables are relatively easy to read, compared to some solution fetched from the nine hells of C++ template meta programming :)

@n.m.couldbeanAI that is interesting, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work as it keeps generating the same assembly instructions.

@Lundin I won't surely fight you about the clarity of a function pointers table, as I needed time to develop my recursive solution and wrap my head around the folded expression used with the initializer list. I'm just curious, can you explain me how would a function pointers table reduce branching compared to a plain switch-case and so be on the same performance level on some CPUs?

@AndreaBocco Worst case = no optimization means a switch will boil down to some O(n) branches, whereas a function pointer table will give direct access, no branches. With optimization on & best case scenario, the compiler will translate the switch into something equivalent to a jump table, but at the same time inline those internal "functions", leading to best performing code. But depending on if cases are adjacent numbers or not, the optimization might end up somewhere in between best & worst case and then it's hard to tell what's most efficient vs function pointer table.

One way to dispatch is using std::variant and std::visit:
using IdVar = std::variant<
        // std::monostate,
        std::integral_constant<Id, Id::Type1>,
        std::integral_constant<Id, Id::Type2>,
        // ...
    >;

IdVar to_IdVar(Id id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case Id::Type1: return std::integral_constant<Id, Id::Type1>{};        
        case Id::Type2: return std::integral_constant<Id, Id::Type2>{};
        // ...
    };
    // throw or have std::monostate as return
}

then your old switch become
void dispatch(const Buffer& buffer)
{
    std::visit(
        [&](auto id) {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::monosate, decltype(id)>) {
                std::cout << "Invalid Id"; 
            } else { // std::integral_constant<Id, xxx>
                obj_type_t<id()> obj;
                obj.deserialize(buffer);
                // other code to print and process the buffer
            }
        }, to_IdVar(buffer.getId()));
}

You do the manual switch only once, then rely on std::visit which is mostly equivalent to a virtual call.
As alternative (or replacement of manual switch in to_IdVar), if enum values are contiguous or with reasonable size, you might create the table yourself:
// Assuming EndValue<Id>() function returning the max value + 1 (as `std::size_t`)
// that `Id` can take

IdVar to_IdVar(Id id)
{
    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(Id) >= EndValue<Id>() {
        return std::monostate{}; // or throw
    }
    return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array<IdVar, sizeof...(Is)> {{
            std::integral_constant<Id, static_cast<Id>(Is)>{}...
        }}[id];
    }(std::make_index_sequence<EndValue<Id>()>());
}


I kind of considered visit at the start just for fun (never actually used one, even though I read about it). I heard most implementations have very poor performances and I have a feeling even a very good implementation will have the same issue as a function pointers table as far as extreme optimization goes.
I'm going to try it nonetheless just to experiment it with this construct. Thanks for the suggestion!

Alternative suggestion:
void generateSwitch(int id, auto&& predicate) {
    switch (id) {
        case Type1::id:
            predicate.template operator()<Type1>();
            break;
        ... 
    } 
} 

Usage example:
void foo(const Buffer& buffer) {
    generateSwitch(buffer.getId(), []<typename T>() {
        T obj;
        obj.deserialize(Buffer);
        // ... other code to print and process the buffer
    });
}

This way you're centralizing type resolution in a way that, imo, is still readable.

This just seem to me like sweeping the dust under the rug. I would still have to type the same amount of code with the same repetition issue, moved to a different function... or am I missing something?

The actual usage code will be written only once in the templated predicate that's being called. The only code that's repeated is case TypeX::id: predicate.template operator()<TypeX>(); break; for every type you want to support. Other solutions also require you to list all types you want to support, on top of lots of template machinery. Which you prefer is up to you, but I find a direct switch-case for type resolution easy to read, maintain and the compiler is guaranteed to optimize it as a switch-case - because it is one. I've edited in a usage example for clarity.
